# fullCalendar Comparing Times

Tags: fullcalendar

on the select event i have the starting date and the ending date of the event as parameter.

also i have a list of times

and i want to see if any of the items of my list is between of the event start and endtime

the 3 objects are in Date Format

how can i compare the 3 Times of the Dates to see if if its true????

```
select: function (start, end, allDay) {
        var defaultTemplate = undefined;
        $.each(jsonTimeTemplates, function(){
            templateStartTime = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(this.Start);
            templateEndTime = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(this.End);
            if(( templateStartTime.getTime() >= start.getTime()) && (  templateStartTime.getTime() <= end.getTime())){
                defaultTemplate = this;
            }
        });            
    },
```

in this case jsonTimeTemplates is my list of objects but when i debug with firebug the if sentence never applies.

here i have an screenshot of my debugging where i have 
8:00>=8:00 && 8:00 <= 8:15
[image]

i hope the dates arent making the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compareDates(dateFrom, dateTo){
    if ( Date.parse( dateTo ) < Date.parse( dateFrom ) )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This function returns true if **dateTo** is smaller than **dateFrom**. You can use this function to reach your goal.

Function call:

```
var startDateStr = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt');
var endDateStr = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt');
compareDates(startDateStr, endDateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the mean time i used the functions gethours and getminutes to do the comparisons. but i hope theres a better way to do this

```javascript
if( ( templateStartTime.getHours() >= start.getHours() ) && ( templateStartTime.getHours() <= end.getHours() ) &&
    (templateStartTime.getMinutes() >= start.getMinutes() ) && ( templateStartTime.getMinutes() <= end.getMinutes() ))
{
    defaultTemplate = this;
}
```